# How to check the version of JupyterHub from command line?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

Maybe this question sounds basic, but how to check from a command line **what is the version of my JupyterHub**? I am running JupyterLab on JupyterHub. I was grepping various configs, helps and now I know what's the version of all the components apart from **JupyterHub**. It'd be great to know how I could do it from the command line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred to be as simple as:

```
pip freeze | grep jupyterhub
jupyterhub==1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even simpler:

```
jupyterhub --version
# 3.1.1
```